# data binding javascript knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

This regards javascript knockouts

HTML

If run this row i get [Object, object]

```
 <p><select data-bind="options: availableRole"></select></p>
```

If i run this row i get nothing

```
    <p><select data-bind="options: availableRoles, value: availableRoles().title, optionText: 'availableRoles().title'"></select></p>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
    self.availableRoles = [

        { title: "Programmer" },
        { title: "Designer" }

    ];
```

How can i show the title programmer and designer?

Comment: ...and just like that you have 3 identical answers...

Comment: I know why it didnt work, the value was wrong. Without the value it works, now i need to figure out how to do with the value =)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is:

```
 <select data-bind="options: availableRoles, optionsText: 'title'"></select>
```

Comment: you shouldn't add another answer when 3 people have already responded with the same answer; you should mark one of the answers as accepted

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `optionsText` binding to bind to a child value as described in the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html):

```
<select data-bind="options: availableRoles, optionsText: 'title'"></select>
```

You can see a [working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/uZjAh/).

Comment: I have tried this it didnt work but now it works ! =) Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide property name in `optionsText` binding:

```
<select data-bind="options: availableRoles, optionText: 'title'"></select>
```

Comment: Im sorry i pasted the wrong one, optionCaption should ofcourse be optionText. I have solved it, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<select data-bind="options: availableRoles, optionsText: 'title', optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
```

For more on this, see: [The "options" binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html)

Answer (score 0):

One thing that all of these answers is missing is the ability to track what role you have selected in your view model. For this, you use the [value](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html) binding in addition to the [options](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) binding.

Here's a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daedalus28/rpNWj/):

And here's the code pasted in for convenience:

```
var viewModel = {
    availableRoles: [
        { title: "Programmer"},
        { title: "Designer" }
    ],
    selectedRole: ko.observable()
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);​


<select data-bind="options: availableRoles, optionsText: 'title', optionsCaption: 'Select...', value: selectedRole"></select>
<pre data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(selectedRole), null, 2)"></pre>
```

​